# Cheapest way to get motion sensor to send SMS or email

Tags: security

I want to build some cheap security system in to cottage without electrical network.

Burglars gets inside always by breaking the window. I think I would need some PIR or microwave sensor. Is there better way how to detect burglar in the cottage?

Then the cottage is located in uninhabited area, so simple sound alarm wouldn't work. I need to send an information about disruption wireless to the owner of the cottage. But how? I was thinking about a cell phone. If I were able to make a program, that would send SMS or email, how would I connect the cellphone to the sensor? What else would work? Could Arduino or rasberry pi send SMS or email? Does any better (cheaper) device, that would be able to send wireless data exist?

I'm searching for an advise from somebody, who has experiences with this and could share his knowledge. Maybe there is completely different and much better way, that's why I described the situation.

Comment: Where would power be taken from? How far from a phone network?

Comment: Cell phone with USB-OTG can connect to a FTDI's USB controller and read directly from its pins. Android drivers exist, so the software side should be easy. Ready-made boards are also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main constraint is how cheap something should be just use an old cellphone and connect it via serial port to a microcontroller (i.e. atmega).

If the microcontroller detects a motion via the motion sensor send some **at commands** via the **serial port** to send a sms.

Here is an example project http://www.8051projects.info/resources/sending-sms-through-nokia-3310-5110.47/

A secound solution which is a semi professional one with a little more costs, would be a **raspberry pi** with an **umts stick** (most of them can be used as gsm modem). You would than run a little python script which sends commands to the gsm modem. For this you could use **gammu** which also has a **python** bindings. http://wammu.eu/python-gammu/ 
But in this solution you have to connect a motion detector circuit to the Raspberry gpio.

Another but more expensive solution would be using a gsm board in addtion to a microcontroller circuit.. But these gsm boards are quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a direction. Is it also possible to control camera or to access internet on the cell phone via the serial port? Just curious.

Comment: @user50222 - how can this work without an "electrical network" - where would power be taken from?

Comment: I think there is the possibility to set up gprs via at commands. Of course you need a power supply. But since the system is inside the building (I am assuming) power should not be a problem. Or is wireing not possible?

Comment: @Andyaka well, battery-powered devices would be required.

Comment: Ok maybe you could if you use the cell phone solution use the cell phone battery to power the control circuit.

Comment: @user50222 which day of the week will the burglar strike? How long will batteries realistically last on an android? Two or three days at best I'd say.

Comment: @Andyaka maybe I was misunderstood. With a cheap phone I ment i.e. one of the old nokias which have the serial port at their connector. Their battery life is better but even if it is 1- 2 weeks there would be a comfort problem...

Comment: @TM90 I'm not getting at you dude - the op has accepted your answer and I was asking him/her how any solution is feasible without a long-term usable power source.

Comment: @Andyaka I know, and you have a valid point and found the main problem for him the power supply.

Comment: I like the old cell phone solution. Really, that's what I was looking for. I have a question. I was searching the phones used in the project you sent, Nokia 3310, 5110 and 6110. In specifications, there is written "Data GPRS: No" for all of them. Does it mean, that I couldn't use the internet, if I choosed to use those models?

Comment: @user50222 sounds like it would not work with these models, what would you do over the internet? I think sending sms would be much easier...

Comment: It would be cheaper to send an email. I'm just observing the possibilities. Also it would be awsome to send a picture of the interier on email, so owner would know, whether it was false alarm, or who and how many people are in the cottage. I don't know if police would come, if there was no evidence.

Comment: @user50222 I am not sure that you can achieve this over at commands. First I do not know if you can control the whole smartphone with it (i.e. camera). Than even if you can establish an gprs connection I do not think it is easy to send a mail. If you want to do this the raspberry solution may be better because you can directly use the umts stick. The power problem remains...